# Muted youtube with iframe and javascript code not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

Good afternoon,

I have the following code:

```
    <div class="videoWrapper">
    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
    <iframe id="myVideo" width="560" height="349" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hygetkMbUto?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=hygetkMbUto" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<style>
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And on the header I have the following javascript in order to have the video muted by default:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var myVideo =  iframe.getElementById('myVideo'); 
myVideo.mute();
</script>
```

But it's not working. The video plays with sound.

Does anyone know the reason?

thanks in advance,
sabrina

Comment: `iframe.getElementById('myVideo');` where do you define `iframe`? I think you mean `document.getElementById('myVideo');` Even then, that'll get you the iframe and not the video element inside.

Comment: Good point George, also you say you have your JavaScript in header? That would mean the code is executed before iframe is added to body so document.getElementById('myVideo'); would return null.

Comment: Ok then, the correct code would be the following:<script type="text/javascript">
var myVideo =  document.getElementById('myVideo'); 
myVideo.mute();
</script> right? However, it's still not working. I'm working in webflow so I can only add code on the middle of the HTML or on the head or before body tag.